# Ignite In-Memory DataGrid for Parquet External storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, caching, parquet, ignite

I am developing an in-memory datagrid over parquet file as external storage

I am reading the file using Spark into a Spark DataFrame. I am able to write a part of this dataframe to Ignite cache and query the cache using SQL.
Like this -> https://medium.com/@sdarlington/the-trick-to-successfully-integrating-apache-ignite-and-pyspark-890e436d09ba

I want to extend this implementation to read and write-through caches.

Everytime I write an sql query, ignite cache should get queried. If data is present, return that. If not present, query the underlying file and return the data.
Continuing with python implementation only.

PS - I found read-through and write-through parameters of cache exist from the CACHE table in SYS schema. Wanted to know how to enable them.

Someone with a solution please do help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Cache Store](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/persistence/custom-cache-store) feature of Ignite. It will do the kind of read/write through that you need.

[Examples](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store) of how to use/design custom cache store.

[Examples](https://github.com/gridgain/python-thin-client/tree/master/examples) of how to use Python to interface with Ignite

Comment: Suppose I have a certain part of the data in the cache.

I want to perform SQL queries like groupby operations or select operations.
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/persistence/external-storage#read-through-and-write-through
This says that SELECT operations do not query external database. How to achieve this now?